# How to deploy RecipePropertyHandler to non development machine?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7-x64, explorer, dllregistration

A while ago I succesfully wrote, compiled and installed the RecipePropertyHandler (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd940375.aspx).
On my development machine it works smoothly and I can install and deinstall the generated DLL and after an explorer restart, I immediately see the new properties getting filled.

All it needs is a simple

```
regsvr32.exe RecipePropertyHandler.dll
```

If I try the same on a different (non-development) machine, the regsvr32 command gives me a totally generic error message (Long text, not helpful) and refuses to intall the DLL:

[image: Very helpful... NOT!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, in fact, it was two things I forgot (just mentioning it here, maybe it will help somebody :-) )

1. I always have to run the commands from an elevated prompt (Administrator DOS-Box). I forgot this sometimes and it makes things very confusing, as the error will not mention a problem with the access-right.
2. (And foremost!) I used VS2013 and compiled with C++2013, that means I have to install the vcredist_x64.exe on the target machine (**D'oh!**).
   The above mentioned error comes from missing c++ libs. It does not really have anything to do with 64/32-bit and especially not with regsvr32 :-)

So I installed it and it works like a charm now. I didn't even have to run the prop.exe tool with the .propdesc file, as I removed the custom property and only use standard ones (as you really should (no, really!)).